# How to select div when scroll window to it

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll

I have a page with several posts div, These posts numbered according to the id like

```
<div id=post-id>
```

I tried building reading bar that increased when hover to div post
[like this](https://jsfiddle.net/hbasheer/0rx53gef/9/)

My problem is how to select div by scroll window to it instead of hover

Answer (score 0):

Check this out.

**Here's the [JsFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/albertonaperijr/0rx53gef/12/)**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function bar(e) {
        var num = $(e).data('id');
        a = $("#content .post").length, $("#navigation  .p").text("Post:" + num);
        $(".processreading").width(Math.ceil(num / a * 100) + "%");
    }

    $('#navigation .p').hide();
    $('div.post').hover(function() {
        $(this).css("background", "#DDD");
        bar(this);
    }, function() {
        $(this).css("background", "#FFF");
    });

    var page1OffsetTop = $('#post-1').offset().top - 40;
    var page2OffsetTop = $('#post-2').offset().top - 40;
    var page3OffsetTop = $('#post-3').offset().top - 40;
    var page4OffsetTop = $('#post-4').offset().top - 40;
    var page5OffsetTop = $('#post-5').offset().top - 40;
    var page6OffsetTop = $('#post-6').offset().top - 40;

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var y = $(this).scrollTop();

        if (y >= page6OffsetTop) {
            $('#post-1').css("background", "#FFF");
            $('#post-2').css("background", "#FFF");
            $('#post-3').css("background", "#FFF");
            $('#post-4').css("background", "#FFF");
            $('#post-5').css("background", "#FFF");
            $('#post-6').css("background", "#DDD");
            bar($('#post-6'));
        } else if (y >= page5OffsetTop) {
            $('#post-1').css("background", "#FFF");
            $('#post-2').css("background", "#FFF");
            $('#post-3').css("background", "#FFF");
            $('#post-4').css("background", "#FFF");
            $('#post-5').css("background", "#DDD");
            $('#post-6').css("background", "#FFF");
            bar($('#post-5'));
        } else if (y >= page4OffsetTop) {
            $('#post-1').css("background", "#FFF");
            $('#post-2').css("background", "#FFF");
            $('#post-3').css("background", "#FFF");
            $('#post-4').css("background", "#DDD");
            $('#post-5').css("background", "#FFF");
            $('#post-6').css("background", "#FFF");
            bar($('#post-4'));
        } else if (y >= page3OffsetTop) {
            $('#post-1').css("background", "#FFF");
            $('#post-2').css("background", "#FFF");
            $('#post-3').css("background", "#DDD");
            $('#post-4').css("background", "#FFF");
            $('#post-5').css("background", "#FFF");
            $('#post-6').css("background", "#FFF");
            bar($('#post-3'));
        } else if (y >= page2OffsetTop) {
            $('#post-1').css("background", "#FFF");
            $('#post-2').css("background", "#DDD");
            $('#post-3').css("background", "#FFF");
            $('#post-4').css("background", "#FFF");
            $('#post-5').css("background", "#FFF");
            $('#post-6').css("background", "#FFF");
            bar($('#post-2'));
        } else if (y >= page1OffsetTop) {
            $('#post-1').css("background", "#DDD");
            $('#post-2').css("background", "#FFF");
            $('#post-3').css("background", "#FFF");
            $('#post-4').css("background", "#FFF");
            $('#post-5').css("background", "#FFF");
            $('#post-6').css("background", "#FFF");
            bar($('#post-1'));
        }

        if (y > 50) {
            var num = $('div.post').data('id');
            $('.bar-container').show();
            $('#main').hide();
            $('#navigation .p').show();
        } else {
            $('.bar-container').hide();
            $("#main").show();
            $('#navigation  .p').hide();
        }
    });

});
```

Hope it helps.